# Having trouble reading XML with R

Tags: xml, r, import

I am using the latest version of R, 3.2.1, with the `XML` package to try to read a xml file and convert it to a data frame.  I am a beginner with xml but have a little experience with R. My xml file is in the format below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<campusRoot>
    <Header baseURL="https://url" date="date" time="time" calendarCookie="0" calendarScope="0">
        <Param name="x" value="adhoc.AdHocFilter-listAdhocData"/>
        <Param name="filterID" value="num"/>
        <Param name="calendarID" value="0"/>
        <Param name="source" value="live"/>
        <Param name="saveAs" value="extract.xml"/>
        <User userID="number" username="user" >
            <financeAccountAccessRights/>
            <financeAccountReportRights/>
            <userGroups>
                <UserGroup groupID="num" name="Ad Hoc" isSecurityRole="false" addContent="true" lock="false"/>
            </userGroups>
        </User>
    </Header>
    <ExportWizard>
        <DisplayPreferences>
            <Field name="sch.number" attribute="sch.number" type="varchar" nooutput="false" seq="" sortOrder="" sortDirection="" alignment="" formatting="" size=""/>
            <Field name="sch.name" attribute="sch.name" type="varchar" nooutput="false" seq="" sortOrder="" sortDirection="" alignment="" formatting="" size=""/>
            <Field name="sch.type" attribute="sch.type" type="varchar" nooutput="false" seq="" sortOrder="" sortDirection="" alignment="" formatting="" size=""/>
            <Field name="sch.comments" attribute="sch.comments" type="varchar" nooutput="false" seq="" sortOrder="" sortDirection="" alignment="" formatting="" size=""/>
            <Field name="sch.schoolID" attribute="sch.schoolID" type="int" nooutput="false" seq="" sortOrder="" sortDirection="" alignment="" formatting="" size=""/>
            <Field name="student.grade" attribute="student.grade" type="varchar" nooutput="false" seq="" sortOrder="" sortDirection="" alignment="" formatting="" size=""/>
        </DisplayPreferences>
        <Extract name="00_Schools">
            <group tier="0" groupBy="All" groupSort="ASC" value="Records" adHocRowLimit="5000000" dataColumns="6">
                <student sch.number="1234" sch.name="name" sch.type="AAA" sch.comments="" sch.schoolID="00" student.grade="00"/>
                <student sch.number="1234" sch.name="name" sch.type="AAA" sch.comments="" sch.schoolID="00" student.grade="00"/>
                <student sch.number="1234" sch.name="name" sch.type="AAA" sch.comments="" sch.schoolID="00" student.grade="00"/>
                <student sch.number="1234" sch.name="name" sch.type="AAA" sch.comments="" sch.schoolID="00" student.grade="00"/>
                <student sch.number="1234" sch.name="name" sch.type="AAA" sch.comments="Middle" sch.schoolID="00" student.grade="00"/>
                <student sch.number="1234" sch.name="name" sch.type="AAA" sch.comments="" sch.schoolID="00" student.grade="00"/>
            </group>
        </Extract>
    </ExportWizard>
</campusRoot>
```

I am trying to get the student data into a data frame with the column names "sch.number", "sch.name", "sch.type", "sch.comments", "sch.schoolID", and "student.grade".  I have tried using the following code to extract the student data.

```
data <- xmlParse("xmlfile.xml", useInternalNodes = FALSE)
root <- xmlRoot(data)
```

After this I can get to the first line of the data by using this code.

```
root[[2]][[2]][[1]][[1]]
```

When I try to get the values for each line using the function `xmlValue()`, I do not get any values back.

```
 > xmlValue(root[[2]][[2]][[1]][[1]])
 character(0)
```

I am not sure how I should loop through the data so that I can extract the data into a data frame.  I have tried to look at other examples but I can not find an example where the data is inside a tag.  Most examples show the data between two tags.   Any suggestions of what I should do?

I would like the result to be the following data frame:

```
sch.number  sch.name  sch.type  sch.comments  sch.schooID  student.grade
1234        name      AAA       NA            00           00
1234        name      AAA       NA            00           00
1234        name      AAA       NA            00           00
1234        name      AAA       NA            00           00
1234        name      AAA       Middle        00           00
1234        name      AAA       NA            00           00
```

Comment: Your nodes don't have any text in them so there's nothing for `xmlValue` to return. What values are you trying to extract? Are you talking about the attributes? What is your expected return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting values with `xmlValue` because the nodes don't have an XML value, the info you need is in the XML attributes.

You can try:

```
library(XML)
data <- xmlParse(xml_data)
res <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,xpathApply(data, "//student",xmlAttrs)))
#or res <- as.data.frame(t(xpathSApply(data, "//student",xmlAttrs)))
res
```

The `xpathApply` will get all the `student` nodes, and apply the `xmlAttrs` function to each of them.

Output:

```
  sch.number sch.name sch.type sch.comments sch.schoolID student.grade
1       1234     name      AAA                        00            00
2       1234     name      AAA                        00            00
3       1234     name      AAA                        00            00
4       1234     name      AAA                        00            00
5       1234     name      AAA       Middle           00            00
6       1234     name      AAA                        00            00
```

Comment: I can see what you mean.  I can get the values using `xmlAttrs()` but I am getting an error when I try to run your code. `Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "c('XMLDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument')"`

Comment: Try removing the `useInternalNodes=FALSE` from your parse statement. Then if you run `class(data)` it should be `XMLInternalDocument` and not `XMLDocument` and run fine.

Comment: Great, you can also use `xpathSApply`, which simplifies the result instead of returning a list. I just added it as a comment in the answer